# x-editable on shown event dropdown (<select />) source refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, x-editable

I'm trying to change a  x-editable source data just before it is shown so that my dropdown menu entries are always fresh even if source changes.

Here is a link to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/XN7np/3/

```
// my source that can change over time
var source = [{'value': 1, 'text': 'fine'}, {'value': 2, 'text': 'bad'}];

$('#my_select').editable({
    'mode'  : 'inline',
    'source': source,
});

$('#my_select').on('shown', function(ev, editable) {
    // now changing my source just before dropdown is shown
    source = [{'value': 1, 'text': 'GOOD'}, {'value': 2, 'text': 'FU'}];

    //$(editable).editable('option', 'source', source); NOT WORKING
    //$('#my_select').editable('option', 'source', source); NOT WORKING
    //$(this).editable('option', 'source', source); NOT WORKING
});
```

any idea?

Comment: too late once it's shown, needs that source to create element to show. Suggest you destroy on close and make own click handler to initialize plugin when link clicked

Comment: This is what doc says about 'shown' event :Fired when container is shown and form is rendered (for select will wait for loading dropdown options).

Comment: well if it's not working, dig through source to see how it should work. destroy on close, create on click is a failry simple solution if not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not see it in the documentation, but you can pass a function to the source parameter like this:

```
var source = [{'value': 1, 'text': 'fine'}, {'value': 2, 'text': 'bad'}];

$('#my_select').editable({
    'mode'  : 'inline',
    'source': function() {
        return source;
    },
});
```

This way it always uses the updated source array. I updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XN7np/4/

Answer (score 0):

This line works:

```
$('#my_select').editable('option', 'source', source);
```

You have to use double quote for "value" and "text", instead of single quote 'value', 'text' for any xeditable source, like source2:

```
 var source2 = [{"value": 1, "text": "fine111"}, {"value": 2, "text": "bad22"}];


 $('#change').click(function(e) {
    $('#my_select').editable('option', 'source', source2)
 });
```

copy above code to your fiddle example and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="editable ea-appsch-agntid" data-type="select" data-source="URL" data-value="">agntname</span>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending the answer a bit more, for fellow programmers, to understand how it helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <td>
    <a href="" class="update_record" data-name="status" id="status" data-type="select" data-pk="{{ $tracker->id }}" data-title="Enter status">{{ $tracker->statname }}</a>
 </td>      

<td> <a href="" class="update_record" data-name="category" id="category" data-type="select" data-pk="{{$tracker->id}}" data-title="Enter category">{{ $tracker->catname }}</a></td>

                                




<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
        }
    });
var statusls = [{'value': 1, 'text': 'Initiated'}, {'value': 2, 'text': 'Interested'}, {'value': 3, 'text': 'Not interested'}, {'value': 4, 'text': 'Details Shared'}, {'value': 5, 'text': 'Negotiating'}, {'value': 6, 'text': 'Onboarded'}, {'value': 7, 'text': 'Being Verified'}, {'value': 8, 'text': 'Picking Up'}, {'value': 9, 'text': 'Live'}, {'value': 10, 'text': 'Dead'}, {'value': 11, 'text': 'Other'}, {'value': 12, 'text': 'Unverified'}, {'value': 13, 'text': 'InProcess'}];

var categoryls = [{'value': 1, 'text': 'Co Shared Offices'}, {'value': 2, 'text': 'Office Space'}, {'value': 3, 'text': 'Event Space'}, {'value': 4, 'text': 'Warehouse'}, {'value': 5, 'text': 'Destination'}, {'value': 6, 'text': 'Agricultural Plot'}, {'value': 7, 'text': 'Classroom | Tution | School'}, {'value': 8, 'text': 'Popup shop'}, {'value': 9, 'text': 'Factory'},  {'value': 10, 'text': 'Agricultural Land'}, {'value': 11, 'text': 'Empty Plot | Ground'}, {'value': 12, 'text': 'Live Streaming'}];

var verify_status = [{'value': 1, 'text': 'Unverified'}, {'value': 2, 'text': 'Inprocess'}, {'value': 3, 'text': 'Verified'}, {'value': 4, 'text': 'Issues'}];


    $('.update_record').editable({
        url: "{{ route('SupplyTrackerupdate') }}",
        type: 'text',  
        'source': function() {
            if ($(this).data('name') ==='status') {                     
                return statusls;
            }   
            if ($(this).data('name') == 'verification_status') {                        
                return verify_status;
            }
            if ($(this).data('name') === 'category') {                      
                return categoryls;
            }   
 
    
            
        },
        name: 'firstname',
        pk: 1,
        title: 'Enter Field'
    });
</script>
```